# Como puedo obtener la lista de rutas (nodos o paths) de la Realtime Database de firebase

Tags: python, firebase

Estoy tratando de averiguar como obtener los nodos de mi base de datos para poder mostrarsela al usuario, uso la libreria de `pyrebase` para el manejo de la db. Llevo dias tratando de buscar en linea una forma pero creo que es totalmente imposible, o bueno no por completo, ya que en diferentes pruebas al azar que he estado haciendo me da solo 2 nodos y no el resto de sus diccionarios. Por favor si alguien puede responder mi pregunta seria maravilloso o si de por si no se puede, dejar de retrasar el desarrollo de mi proyecto solo por esto.

Gracias por sus respuestas...